# What is the purpose of the [version] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag has over 5,000 questions associated with it. However to me it seems to always be how to do X in version Y of Z.

I would say that Z should be a tag and potentially Y-Z but not [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) on its own.

If there is a specific use for this tag, it'd be great to hear it and get the description updated accordingly. It currently states:

> Version defines an unique state of a computer software or a file.

Comment: It is one of the standard programming problems.  Necessary to add to a hopelessly broad tag like [java] to make the question more specific.  The associated [versioning] tag can cover the same ground but the word "version" often appears as-is in whatever the OP is looking at.  The tag has experts, but they are bit hard to find back because existing answers are so extremely popular, earning many hundreds of votes.  I can see Pascal Thivent with 11 answers and me with 18, there no doubt are more.   It gets the job done.